# swift - tableviews, a point in the right direction

Tags: swift, scrollview, tableview

i am working on an app that lets the user enter some information which then gets loaded online. As part of my project, i want the user to enter some information and it would be alot easier for them if there was a table allowing them to enter it , ok so the problem is, I have a view controller with a scrollview which gives me some more space i can work with.
 I want a way where i can display a table 5 columns across and the rows will depend upon the user, the table should only take a small amount of space on the scrollview, the table will allow information to be entered into the cell which later will be saved. i just need a point in the right direction on how to go about this problem.  I am fairly new to swift and any guidance would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement of having both columns and rows—I would look into [creating a `UICollectionView`](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1) and populating the cells with `UITextField`s.

Comment: yes i am trying to implement this, i am having problems with extracting the data from the textfield from the collection view? how would i go about doing this, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Please learn about `UITableviewController` here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/

There are no columns, just rows, and you don't need an extra scrollview to contain your tableview in. There are plenty of tutorials out there that teach how to work with table view controllers. You should seek guidance here if you have a particular problem with implementing them.

Comment: This is different from what the user wants to do.  The user wants a "table", not a `UITableView`.

Comment: @nhgrif It says TableView in the title... How does that refer to table more than UITableView?

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense to use a `UITableView` for what he's asking to do.  What he wants to do is more important than the class he *thinks* he needs to use.

Comment: not a very helpful answer. try to read the actual question next time and not just the title